# Error doing modulo math

Tags: java, oop, jvm

I greet you all. I need someone to help review this printChar(char ch1, char ch2, int num) method.
It's purpose is to take two character arguments, a starting point ch1, and end point ch2. Print the characters on the console in ascending order from ch1 through ch2 until it reaches point(num), break, then continue printing on the next line.

the type of error faced here is a logical one, I believe. please help out. here is the code.

```
public static void printChars(char ch1, char ch2, int num) {
    while (ch1 < ch2) {
        System.out.print(ch1++ + " ");
        if ((ch1 % num) == 4) {
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    System.out.print(ch2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printChars('A', 'H', 4);
    }
}
```

---

here is the output it displays

```
run:
A B C 
D E F G 
HBUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

intead of

```
A B C D
E F G H
```

Comment: print num characters, or ch1 to ch2 ?

Comment: what "reaches point(num)" means?

Comment: what does it should output for this example?

Comment: `(ch1 % num)== 4` will always return false if `num==4`

Comment: the 'num' variable is an interger that tells the character printing to continue on the next line when it reaches 'num' @vodka

Comment: i expect the output to be A B C D...next line...E F G H @m.antkowicz

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at how the modulo operator (`%`) works. `n%n` will not return `n` but 0

you might want to change `if((ch1 % num)== 4)` to `if((ch1 % num)== 0)`

**EDIT**: Now i understood what you really wanted ;) You should implement a counter that is running parallel to ch1 and check the counter (`if((counter % num)==0)`)! With that counter you can print the newlines at the right positions.

Answer (score 0):

you should add some couter to count characters in line

```
public static void printChars(char ch1, char ch2, int num)
{
   int counter = 0;

   while(ch1 <= ch2)
   {
       System.out.print(ch1++ + " ");  
       counter++;

       if( counter%num == 0 )
       {
           System.out.println("");
       } 
    }
}
```

also you can use **ch1 <= ch2** instead of printing ch2 at the end

Answer (score -1):

your code its almost right, i make some small changes and looks like what you want:

```
public static void printChars(char ch1, char ch2, int num) {
    int index = 1;
    while (ch1 < ch2) {
        System.out.print(ch1 + " ");
        if ((index % num) == 0) {
            System.out.println("");
        }
        index++;
        ch1++;
    }
    System.out.print(ch2);

}
```

Please let me know if this is what you want...

***Example***

***printChars('A', 'W', 4);***

```
A B C D 
E F G H 
I J K L 
M N O P 
Q R S T 
U V W
```

The probem you have is that **%** must be compared to **0** beacause it returns the module o ***ch1*** and ***num***

Comment: [comment to version before edit] won't work when starting from **B** for example: printChars('B', 'I', 4);

Comment: Yes it worked for num = 4. but won't if num = 3 @melli-182

Comment: thanks both for the comments, another issue was that the module comparision was between the char and the "point" and should be made with an auxiliar index